# How to reach down to these span's and concatenate their id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have:

```
<li id="foo">
   <span> bar </span>
   <ul>
   <li>
      <span id="1234"></span>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span id="5678"></span>
   </li>

   </ul>
</li>
```

I need concatenate the span ids and make var foobar = "12345678"

P.S. I need start working from the top Li which has the id of "foo" since the span ids can be dynamic/unknown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var foobar = "";
$('#foo span[id]').each(function(){
   foobar += this.id
})
```

Comment: This is ok, but it will hit the top <span>bar</span>.
That may be the intent of the OP, but it looks like he wants to target span's nested inside of nested LI

Comment: This is a half solution because he also wants to construct the variable name "foobar".

Comment: Either that, or the OP needs to find more variation in his choice of values... :)

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry my code post above didn't really show what I'm working on. Actually the <span>br<span> also has an id let's say "7890". and There are multiple li's with id = "foo", so I gave a bad example. I think it will be a mess to scratch this off so I will choose this as the answer to this question. But I will start another question for a much more complicated situation but a lot more closer to what I'm looking for... Thanks guys.

Comment: For the other question, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890832/how-to-select-multiple-elements-with-two-each-functions-nested

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
window.concat = "";
$('#foo li span').each(function () {
  window.concat += $(this).attr('id');
});
console.log(window.concat);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nfsg5/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var foobar = '';
$('#foo li span').each(function() { 
    foobar += $(this).attr('id'); 
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pZDWF/)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else is using `.each()`. This is a little simpler with `.map()`...

```
var ids = $.map($("#foo span[id]"), function(el) {
                                       return el.id;
                                    }).join("");
```

I also used the *has-attribute* selector to make sure you only get `span` elements that have an ID attribute.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rgNRH/

---

Or you can use the native `Array.prototype.map`...

```
var ids = $("#foo span[id]").toArray()
                            .map(function(el) {
                                    return el.id;
                                 }).join("");
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rgNRH/1/

---

Nice thing about `.map()` is that it doesn't rely on any external variable, so you can save and reuse the function...

```
var mappers = {
    getIDs: function(el, i) { return el.id; }
    /* other mapping functions */
};
```

...then use it when needed...

```
var ids = $.map($("#foo span[id]"), mappers.getIDs).join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = '';
$('#foo li span').attr('id',function() {
    ids += this.id;
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv2Qt/2/)**