# How to select multiple elements with two .each() functions nested?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok guys, as promised, here is the real deal, first the sample html:

```
<li data-foo="bar">
    <span id="a"></span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span id="1"></span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span id="b"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>

        <li>
            <span id="2"></span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span id="c"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>

    </ul>

</li>

<li data-foo="bar">
    <span id="d"></span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span id="3"></span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span id="e"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>

        <li>
            <span id="4"></span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span id="f"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>

    </ul>

</li>
```

**I want to get the window to pop up "12", then pop up "34"**... so here is my nested functions attempt:

```
<script>
    var poptext = "";

    $('li[data-foo=bar]').each(

    function () {

        $(this li span).each(function () {
            poptext = poptext + $(this).attr("id");
        }

        alert(poptext);
        poptext = "";

        );

    }

    );
</script>
```

This does not seem to be working, I think Jquery might got confused with multiple "this" keywords? Also there could be something wrong with the selector for those spans to begin with.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the direct descendant selector: `>`

Used like this:

```
$('li[data-foo=bar]').each(function () {
     var poptext = "";        
     $(this).find('> ul > li > span').each(function () {
         poptext = poptext + $(this).attr("id");
     });
     alert(poptext);
});
```

Will only select the nodes that are direct children of the previous expression on the left hand side.

A more verbose, but maybe readable version could be:

```
$(this).children('ul').children('li').children('span') // selects the same
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/xYgJg/

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your code, `$(this li span)` should be `$('li span', this)` also your logic is off, you aren't filtering out the spans with the letter ids.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Yeah i'm not sure how to reach the those exact points. Those spans should be located 3 levels down from the root li. (LI>UL>LI>SPAN)